# Sandboxing user code with Erlang

Tags: erlang, sandbox, unsafe

As far as I know Erlang provides advanced features for error handling and isolation of processes.

I'm building a system that allow user to submit their code to be executed on the shared server environment and need to make it safe.

Requirements are:

- limit CPU and Memory usage individually for each user-process.
- forbid user-process to communicate with other processes (except some processes specially designed for such purpose).
- forbid access to all sytem resources (shell, file system, ...).
- terminate user-process in case of errors or high resource consumption.

Is it possible to to all this with Erlang and keep it performance efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been work done on Safe Erlang in the past and you can find several papers about it.
The ErlHive project addresses the problem in an interesting way.

Answer (score 2):

In general, Erlang doesn't provide means to sandbox code which a user can inject. You can try writing your own piece of protection code, but it is rather hard.

A better choice would probably be a language like "safe haskell":

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/safe-haskell.html

which is specifically built to do this kind of thing.

The isolation provided by Erlang is not intended to protect against malicious modules being injected. In fact, there is no such protection in the distributed case either. As soon as two machines are connected, there is no limit to what you can do to the other machine.